# Running laravel queue:work on a shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I want my laravel queue:work to keep running on a shared hosting, **this is a shared hosting (am not on a VPS)** I can't install anything because almost all online sources when I was searching for this suggest installing supervisor. So basically I thought I could just create a cron job that checks if queue is not running and starts it, any help on how to go about this because am kinda stuck, thanks.

**P.S. Am on a Linux server and Laravel 5.3**

Answer (score 19):

As you mentioned you are using shared hosting, You follow the below steps.

**Step 1.**
you need to setup your queue driver as `database`

**Step 2**
 you need to setup a cron job with with the following command 
`php /path/to/application/artisan queue:work --queue=high,default`.

You can give a try. I hope it will work.

Comment: ok first am using sqs but that doesn't matter i guess, second how often should the cron job execute because if its once, should i be worried that the server might be temporary down and the process be terminated?

Comment: cron needs to be triggered every min, then only u will get the maximum accuracy of job

Comment: will the next command replace the previous one or will there be a case of multiple commands executing parallelly

Comment: No, it won't replace even its running on parallelly because as soon as one job is picked from DB it will be flagged. Then unflagged jobs will be picked for process in next call

Comment: am more of looking for a solution that will terminate the previous command and execute a new one

Comment: Okay . It's totally up to you.

Comment: is there a flag that can just execute the current jobs and quit, like --once executes one job so something like --current, i have used queue:work and it continues to wait even though all jobs are finished

Comment: please check on this link ... https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#queue-priorities

Comment: But this approach is consuming a lot of RAM, what to do to avoid so?

Comment: @Ishaan You may need to add a flag like this
php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default --stop-when-empty

Answer (score 18):

**Laravel >= 5.7**

Adding this line to the scheduler in app\Console\Kernel.php and then setting up a cron job to run the scheduler, ensures that the queue gets serviced every minute.

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')
    ->everyMinute()
    ->withoutOverlapping();
```

For Cpanel servers, the Cron statement might look like:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/{account_name}/live/artisan schedule:run
```

where {account_name} is the user account that cpanel is running under and live is the folder of the laravel application

Source: https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/using-queues-on-shared-hosting-with-laravel

**Laravel <= 5.6**

`--once` To force worker to exit after running one job

`--tries` The maximum number of times a job may be attempted

`--timeout` The maximum number of seconds that jobs can run may be specified

`withoutOverlapping()` By default, scheduled tasks will be run even if the previous instance of the task is still running. To prevent this, you may use the withoutOverlapping method

`sendOutputTo()` Send the output to a file for later inspection

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --timeout=60 --tries=1 --once')
    ->everyMinute()
    ->withoutOverlapping()
    ->sendOutputTo(storage_path() . '/logs/queue-jobs.log');
```

---

**Laravel All version**

If you don't want to use the `--once' or '--max-time' options, it's better to use the restart command to avoiding memory leak and make apply code changes.

```
$schedule->command('queue:restart')
    ->everyFiveMinutes();
```

---

Laravel <= 5.2

Not recommended:

The --daemon options continued to run, which you can run once from the command line if you have ssh or cpanel 'command' access.

Comment: Thanks, first solution looks perfect. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps

Answer (score 7):

the best way is to set followin command on your tasks of panel (I'm using  plesk control panel, it makes me able to set task there)

```
php artisan queue:work --once
```

***Note:*** in my shared host, I must set following values because of their server configuration:

1. **php:** /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -q
2. **artisan:** /var/www/vhosts/t4f.ir/httpdocs/artisan
3. **my command:** then I should write the command

so, the result would  be  like this:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/t4f.ir/httpdocs/artisan queue:work --once
```

there is another option for runtime which I set to Cron type with value of: *** * * * *** which means, every minute this code will be executed. as I used --once in end of my commad, once it execute the command and job has been finished, it will be terminated.
regarding to concurrent execution, I'm not worried about beacuase it's handling in  queueing system and it's responsibility of this system.

Comment: Is the `-q` for making it quiet?

Comment: @MichaelSørensen  to be honest, I  don't know :) I'm using it based on my last searches, but glad to hear from you, if you will find it. I will learn.

Answer (score 7):

With Laravel 8 you have the option `--max-time` for `queue:work` that allows it to stop job processing after some amount of time.

```
php artisan queue:work --max-time=300
```

You can setup a cron job, for example, every 5 minutes to run job processing and set the `--max-time` option to 5 minutes (300 seconds). In that case, cron will run job processing, after 300 seconds `queue:work` will exit, and, in a couple of seconds, cron will run job processing again, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution that worked for me after searching for days.

`flock -n /tmp/latavel_queues.lockfile /usr/bin/php /path/to/laravel/artisan queue:listen`

See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/database-queue-on-shared-hosting

Answer (score 2):

One more solution (I solved same problem in this way). You can make script like this:

```
# getting running processes with name "queue:work"
QUEUE_STATUS=$(ps aux | grep "queue:work")

# check is queue:work started, if no, start it
if $( echo $QUEUE_STATUS | grep --quiet 'artisan queue:work')
then
    exit;
else
    php ~/public_html/artisan queue:work
fi
```

and run it in CRON. I run every 10 min.

Comment: the cron detect that it has the queue work but when i check it on shell, it doesnt have any process about queue

Answer (score 2):

Try adding two cron jobs:

1. To clear cache:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/php /home/<path-to-project>/artisan cache:clear
```

2. To run the scheduler

```sh
/usr/local/bin/php /home/<path-to-project>/artisan schedule:run
```

**Also, make sure that your app\Console\Kernel.php is having something like**

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3')
            ->cron('* * * * *')
            ->withoutOverlapping(5);
    }
```

*Remove the first job (the one to remove cache) if the queue starts working*

Comment: I have done exactly the above and nothing runs

Answer (score 0):

I figured a hack to accomplish this

On file `Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php` my current laravel version (5.3) is on *line 151*; on function `runNextJob($connectionName, $queue, WorkerOptions $options)` add `else` as below

```
if ($job) {
    return $this->process(
        $connectionName, $job, $options
    );
 } else {
    $this->stop();
}
```

Now create cron job that will run the number of times you like with command `php artisan queue:work` the moment the queue is exhausted, it will exit (but should be frequent as the process exists)

**UPDATE:** Using task schedular with `withoutOverlapping()` prevents further calls of the command if its already running, so this is a better option considering the previous one is a change you have to make everytime you `composer install` or `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

// step 1: To run the scheduler

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/USERNAME/public_html/PROJECT_FOLDER/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

// step 2   in kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('queue:work', [
        '--max-time' => 300
        ])->withoutOverlapping();
```

// step 3
test it. ;)