# How to correctly execute laravel queue worker in shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, cpanel

I have email sending service to send broadcast to all customers. Customer number can be above 10k and I am using laravel queue for this.

I have made chunks with size 100 and looped over chunks to send email using following mail class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

/**
 * Class BroadcastEmail
 * @package App\Mail
 */
class BroadcastEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * Create a new body instance.
     *
     * @param $title
     * @param $body
     * @param $url
     * @param $image
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($title, $body, $url, $image)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->body = $body;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    /**
     * Build the body.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->subject($this->title)
            ->view('emails.broadcast')
            ->with(
                [
                    'body' => $this->body,
                    'url' => $this->url,
                    'image' => $this->image
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

In the local server, I just run `queue:work` command in console and everything works perfectly untill i terminate the queue worker.

However I don't have console access to my production server. I have shared hosting cpanel.

What should I do to execute all the jobs in the queue in production ?

Should I make a cron job to run queue:work command and execute it periodically ?

or

I have to execute queue:work once programmatically in server ?

Which of these will work or is there any better correct way to execute queue worker in cpanel ?

Any kind of suggestions are appreciated.

P.S. I have already visited this question before asking since I don't get any idea from the answer.

[Running laravel queue:work on a shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141652/running-laravel-queuework-on-a-shared-hosting)

Comment: As it said in the answer you'll need to set up a cronjob which executes the worker for you.

Comment: @PtrTon So , I have to execute the queue:work command every minute ?

Comment: Yes, that's probably your best option unless you get cli access

Comment: @PtrTon Hmm okay