# Laravel queue:work on production shared hosting

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

Laravel should run php artisan queue:work to listen asynchronous job. If it run on local it will not be hurt. But, If it running on production shared hosting that very restricted we cannot even install additional module. How should I do ?

Note: I cannot install Supervisor on shared hosting.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141735/5192105

Comment: That question you should ask your hosting service provider.

Comment: most of the shared hosting gives you the ability to define your cron job commands, what shared hosting you are using?

Comment: @mohammad.kaab what should I do with cron ?

Comment: Define your commands, like ```php artisan queue:listen```

Comment: @mohammad.kaab Should I define like * * * * * ?

Comment: Yes, you should define the timing beforehand, But it should be defined already.

Comment: @mohammad.kaab it means every minute ? Will the new command replace the command before ? How if the command before has running some job ?